# Installing Apache solr Centos 5 Dedicated server

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, drupal-7, centos5

I have a CentOS 5.6 Dedicated server with the MySQL and Apache installed on it. I want to install Apache solr on it.

Does anyone know what is the best way to do it and is there any step by step tutorial that will show me how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this one [Installing Apache Solr on CentOS](http://blog.nexcess.net/2011/12/30/installing-apache-solr-on-centos/)

Answer (score 1):

you can see this on http://janaksingh.com/blog/apachesolr-search-drupal-centos-107

Comment: Perfect, The link give the process for PHP and Drupal.